# in jade, how do you used the same block name in more than one level?

Tags: node.js, pug, template-engine

have a working base file and extension, `page.jade` and `layout.jade`

wish to put an extension *between* them that will modify `page`'s `block` before `layout` gets it.  possible to retain the block names and do this?  otherwise, much code needs changing.

currently, in `layout.jade`:

```
body
  p Greetings
  block content
  p Goodbye!
```

and in `page.jade`

```
extends layout
block content
  p Nice to meet you
```

results in:

```
Greetings
Nice to meet you
Goodbye!
```

wish to insert an extension `middle.jade` *between* `layout.jade` and `page.jade`.  `page.jade` would extend `middle`, and `middle` would extend `layout`.

for example, `middle.jade`

```
extends layout
block content
  p Good Morning
  block content
```

with target result:

```
Greetings
Good Morning
Nice to meet you
Goodbye
```

when I try this, the `middle.jade` block is not picked up at all.

am I being stupid and missing something obvious?  or is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Either nest it differently

```
block page_content
  block content
```

or use `block append` / `block prepend`

```
block append page_content
  blabla
```

Comment: thanks.  quite intrusive to rename all the blocks in all the files, so wish to dodge that.  will re-try `block append` and post back.